# Config-Class in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, configuration

what is the pythonic way to use a config in object oriented programming?

I thought of the following 2 setups:

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigClass("config_file.cfg")
        self.worker = WorkerClass(self.config.USER_NAME)
        self.worker2 = WorkerClass2(self.config)

    def run(self):
        self.worker.work()
        self.worker2.work()

class ConfigClass():
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read(file_name)

    @property
    def USER_NAME(self):
        return self.config.get("USER", "NAME")

class WorkerClass():
    def __init__(self, user_name):
        self.user = user_name

    def work(self):
        print(self.user)

class WorkerClass2():
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.user = self.config.USER_NAME

    def work(self):
        print(self.user)
```

Is it preferred to pass the config object or just the needed strings or is there a better different approach which I didn't mention?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

in flask we have the factory pattern to initialize the app in simple and flexible ways between diff environment.
using [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) package, allow to you to load variable in a **.env** file which will be unique for each environment (dev, staging, prod...).
you can use the same pattern.

here is an example of **.env** file locally, and you want to use diff databases for diff purposes (dev, testing ...)

```
DATABASE_URI=postgresql://exercise_user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/exercise_new_db
DATABASE_TEST_URI=postgresql://exercise_user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/exercise_db_test
DATABASE_DOCKER_URI=postgresql://docker_exercise_user:pass@db/docker_exercise_db
```

to let the software know which environment is running on, write a **shell** **start.sh** script that will export the main environment variable

```
export ENV=development
python main.py
```

and here is an example of config file, where you define an abstract class contains all configurations that are the same for all envs, then you create for each environemnt a class inherited from that base class, and these class contains unique configuration.

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv


basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
# here we we load environment variables from .env, must be called before init. class
load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), verbose=True)


class ConfigFactory(object):
    def factory():
        env = environ.get("ENV", "development")
        if env is 'testing':
            return Testing()
        elif env is 'development':
            return Development()
        elif env is 'docker':
            return Docker()
        elif env is 'production':
            return Production()


class Config:

    """Base config."""
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class Development(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DATABASE_URI')


class Testing(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DATABASE_TEST_URI')


class Docker(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DATABASE_DOCKER_URI')


class Production(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DATABASE_URI')
```

and finally you import you config class in your main file and call it